# How to protect user of library from a false initialisation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a dll which contains a type which shoul be able to represent an integer value from 32 to 126 and is called "PByte" (for Printable Byte). The problem is that I want to protect the user from initializing the type with e.g. 1000. This should not throw an exception. It should prevent from compiling, like Visiual Studio does trying to initialize for example a byte with 256. The type is  initialized in the constructor.

```
public PByte(int value)
{
    /* if (value < 32 || value > 126)
        throw new ArgumentException("\"" + value + "\" is an invalid value!"); */
    this._value = value;
}
```

This

```
PByte pb = new PByte(2000);
```

should not be compilable.

Comment: This is not literally possible without modifying the .NET compiler.

Comment: And how would you prevent something like this? `int x = 3; int y = 300; PByte pb = new PByte(x + y);` Or similar code taking input from the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a runtime exception to occur on compile time? That's impossible!

Should `PByte pb = new PByte(get399());` compile? No, but how can you know what `get399()` does without running the program?

But first of all you should make the parameter be a `byte` type. That will produce compile time exceptions for numbers outside 0-255.

Answer (score 2):

The only option you have is to assign a null character when out of range. Something like this.

```
public struct PByte : IEquatable<PByte>
{
    readonly byte _value;
    public PByte(byte value)
    {
        this._value = (byte)( value > 31 && value < 128 ? value : 0);
    }
    public byte Value { get { return this._value; } }
    public char Char { get { return (char)_value; } }
    public bool Equals(PByte other)
    {
        return _value.Equals(other._value);
    }        
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1 = new PByte(1000); // Won't compile
        var p2 = new PByte(5);      //'\0'
        var p3 = new PByte(65);     //'A'
        var p4 = new PByte(125);    //'}'
        var p5 = new PByte(175);    //'\0'
    }
}
```